# Close notification event in Vaadin Window

Tags: java, javascript, html, vaadin

I am writing an application in Vaadin that searches for results. A form is used to specify the criteria and a table is used to represent the results.
I also want to show the amount of results found in a Window.Notification of Vaadin.
My problem is that I want the notification to stay there until the user clicks on it so it does not disappear after a few seconds.
If you just enter a large delay time, then if you don't click on these notifications and do several searches, all result notifications will come over each other. So if you then click on them to remove them, you will see the amount of results from your previous search.
This is what I want to avoid.

Notifications are added to the Window and as far as I can see, you can't get a reference to them to update them. So you can't change the current notification if there is already one present. After it is painted it is removed from the `LinkedList<Notification> notifications` of com.vaadin.ui.Window

One of the things I was looking at is how Vaadin closes the notification after you click on it so that maybe I can do the same before each search so that the previous notification is removed and the new search adds a new notification.
But so far I am unable to find how it is done.

A notification in html is shown as a div. So maybe there is a javascript I could call in Vaadin to remove that div?

Does anyone know how the timer works for closing the notification after the defined delay? Will this call a javascript that I could also call?

Answer (score 1):

If the delay on the notification is -1, it has to be clicked on by the user. Unless the notification is of type `TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE`, you have to create a notification object yourself:

```
Notification message = new Notification("Message", Notification.TYPE_HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
message.setDelayMsec(-1);
getWindow().showNotification(message);
```

There is no mechanism in Vaadin to listen for hide events of notifications. You could create your own widget derived from `VNotification` to transmit this condition back to the server.

Comment: yes, but if you set the delay to -1, no other actions can be done without closing the results notification. What I would like to do is show the results and the result notification. The user can work with the results and is still able to see the total result count. I know there is no mechanism foreseen in Vaadin to do this, but Vaadin does the action that I want to trigger after the delay seconds have passed or when the notification is clicked. I would like to know if this action can be called directly. I will look at your suggestion about VNotification

Comment: @gizmo753 Sounds like you have to develop your own widget